# Regular expression in webdriver

Tags: regex, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm new to `Webdriver`. In below syntax value `37500` is dynamic, so please help me how doing regular expression for the same

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='37500']/td[2]")).click();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show some example html fragments that demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you could use XPath 2.0, you would be able to call the [`matches()` XPath function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-matches) but I don't think any browser you can use via Selenium Webdriver supports that.

In XPath 1.0 (supported by Selenium), you should have the [`number()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926043.aspx) available. It's possible to use it to check whether a value is numeric.

```
number(value) = number
```

Means that the value cast to a number remains the same (so it's not text, not a boolean, nor a node set).

Therefore the following XPath expression should allow you to find the second `td` in each element that has a numeric `id` and work around the lack of regex support:

```
.//*[number(@id) = @id]/td[2]
```

To find all matching elements on the page, use `findElements`

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[number(@id) = @id]/td[2]")).click();
```

Comment: I tried this syntax but it wont move to next row. Values are added in first row itself. Pls help

Comment: @user3894096 this is probably because you're using `findElement`, which only returns the first `WebElement` found as opposed to `findElements`, which returns a `List` of all matching `WebElement`s. Check [the Javadoc](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html). Let me know if this is the case and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: It isn't Selenium that doesn't support XPath 2, it's the browsers (*none* of them do): http://www.w3.org/XML/Query/#xpath2implementations

Comment: @Arran true, either way, it's not yet possible to use it in Selenium Webdriver automated tests.

Answer (score 0):

If the value changes dynamically in this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='37500']/td[2]")).click();
```

then using `id` attribute will not work. Please check the root html try giving it with the Parent tag. eg: `/html/body//div/td[2]`

or if it has a unique field try using different attribute.

Comment: Thanks Pavithra. I found that parent path driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='vadivelan']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).click(); here dynamic value is tr[2]/td[2] Please help me

Comment: Can you please send the Entire DOM element?
If only the value of /td[2] and tr[2] changes then the xpath can be given like this itself which you have sent.